# Automatically upload swagger documentation of a lambda service to my organisation's Swaggerhub

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-serverless

I have a requirement, where my AWS lambda service supports a RESTful API. I want to create a swagger document of this lambda and then automatically upload the document to my organisation's SwaggerHub. My AWS lambda is written in NodeJS and deployed through serverless framework.
Till now, the solutions I have seen, they would host the swagger document UI in a localhost server. But I want the swagger document to be uploaded to my organisation's SwaggerHub API.
I need some guidance on how to do it